# Add extra markup to WP menus

Tags: php, menus, html

Have been asked to redevelop a HTML website in to a WP theme, it has quite an advanced menu structure and i'm not quite sure how I can replicate it.
The second menu item has a sub-menu, but it is not just a 'ul' inside a 'li', there are extra divs etc.. because the drop down has a 3 column layout with 2 columns containing the child links and the 3rd containing content.

This is an example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav three">
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Parent Link</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li> 
                    <div class="yamm-content">
                      <div class="row">

                        <ul class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-unstyled two">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 4</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-unstyled two">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Child Link 8</a></li>
                        </ul>

                          <ul class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 list-unstyled two">
                            <li>
                                <h5>A title here</h5>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dart">
                                Some text here
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I have so far managed to figure out the classes and extra divs using the wp_nav_menu $args and a walker, here is what I have so far:

```
    class Child_Wrap extends Walker_Nav_Menu
    {
        function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
        {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\"><li><div class=\"yamm-content\"><div class=\"row\">\n";
        }
        function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
        {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent</div></div></li></ul>\n";
        }
    } 

<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'Header Nav', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav three', 'walker' => new Child_Wrap())); ?>
```

But rather than having sub-links in the menus dashboard, is there a way of inserting a secondary menu to be the sub-menu, which can create the columns?

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'Submenu 1', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-unstyled two', 'link_before' => '<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> ')); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: you'll need a custom menu walker. if you search for that here you'll find some answers that will get you started.

Comment: I have found a good example for the walker which will help me to add the additional div's and ul's before the sub-menu, but still not quite sure how I am going to achieve the columns.

Comment: Do what you can then post your code. You will get more help if you get started yourself and post code, even if broken code. My "walker" code, if you are interested, is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+menu+walker

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum I have had a go and updated my original post, hope this gets me a bit closer to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing a menu on a bootstrap based theme, I now use the following Walker:

```
'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu

class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

// add classes to ul sub-menus
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
    // depth dependent classes
    $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
    $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
    $classes = array(
        'sub-menu',
        ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
        ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
        'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' . "\n";
}

  function start_el ( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    // Most of this code is copied from original Walker_Nav_Menu
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id)
                            FROM wp_postmeta
                            WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent'
                            AND meta_value='".$item->ID."'");

    if ( $depth == 0 && $has_children > 0  ) {

    $output .= $indent . '<li class="dropdown">';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '<span class="caret"></span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    } else {

    $output .= $indent . '<li>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    }

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args, $id );
  }

}
```